# Blazor AuthorizeView - Is there any way to ignore authorization at the application level?

Tags: blazor, authorization

I am currently trying to write a Blazor component library to be used across different Blazor applications and I would like the ability to toggle whether there is security or not.

So essentially to write a Blazor component that if you so choose, doesn't require authorization, but if you do require authorization you'll need to assign whatever roles the component requires to the ClaimsIdentity in the AuthenticationState.

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="SomeRole">
    <Authorized>
    ...Authorized stuff
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
    ...Not authorized stuff
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

So in essence, can I instruct the component to completely ignore the requirement to authorize the user for role `SomeRole` as above and treat the current session as authorized? Ideally this would be done from a config setting.

My thinking at the moment is this can only be achieved using an `@if` statement within the component itself to check for the setting and apply different front end code based on what it finds.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to build the `AuthorizeView` view component into your components is a very clumsy and error prone approach.  It is a component itself.  To implement security you need to take a step back and implement the logic within `AuthorizeView`.

Let me show you an example that I use to demonstrate the kind of authorization you can build into library components.  This one hides/displays a button, such as the edit button, on list rows based on the user passing a defined policy.

```cs
public class UIAuthorizeButton : UIButton
{
    [CascadingParameter] public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthTask { get; set;     
    [Parameter] public string Policy { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    [Parameter] public object? AuthFields { get; set; } = null;
} = default!;
    [Inject] protected IAuthorizationService authorizationService { get; set; } =default!;

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (AuthTask is null)
            throw new Exception($"{this.GetType().FullName} must have access to cascading Paramater {nameof(AuthTask)}");

        await this.CheckPolicy();
    }

    protected virtual async ValueTask CheckPolicy()
    {
        var state = await AuthTask!;
        var result = await this.authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(state.User, AuthFields, Policy);
        // code to hide the component if fails
    }
}
```

The button stuff doesn't matter.  The component uses policies and interacts with the `IAuthorizationService` to verify if the current user passes the policy.

In this instance the AuthFields is a simple object that contains a Guid from the `OwnerId` field in the record.  There's a custom policy defined that checks the provided Id against the user's Id in the `ClaimsPrincipal` available through `state.User`.

You can see the button in action here: https://blazr-demo.azurewebsites.net/weatherforecast/list .  You select which user you are logged in as in the top bar.

Note that providing all the backing infrastructure that makes this work is far beyond the scope of StackOverflow answer!

How useful this is and how much you can achieve will depend on the level of your knowledge on Authorization and defining and building Authorization Policies.

Here are some resources that you may find useful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/october/cutting-edge-policy-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/custom-authorization

Comment: I like the simplicity of the auth blazr-demo site linked to above. Could MrC / Shaun confirm if the following GitHub repository contains the code for this site https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.Auth

Comment: @camelCase - I'm not sure what's in that Repo.  There's a repo here that has that code base and demos various other Authorization techniques. https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Authorization.

Comment: I found the smaller code base at github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.Auth to be a good tutorial starting point because it strips Auth back to the essentials. I used your example to embed a developer-only login component into my Blazor Server system, the component offers 6 fixed user accounts defined in memory for the 6 user roles in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the user against the policy and cascade the value down using the authorization handler and regular cascadingvalue tag-helper.

This way you have one place where the policy is defined.